# Accept an unspecified number of properties with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a requirement for a URL structure that supports an unspecified number of path parameters for a given route.

As an example, suppose we have a route to the `thing` Component, which will handle all sorts of things, with a different number of properties:

```
/thing/animal/mammal/four-legged-mammal/cat/leopard
/thing/animal/mammal/four-legged-mammal/horse
/thing/animal/fish/salmon
```

The only way I would know how to handle this, would be to hardcode a route like this:

```
<Route path='/thing/:prop1/:prop2/:prop3/:prop4/:prop5/:prop6' component={Thing}>
</Route>
```

That sucks.

Is there any way to declare something like `/thing/any/number/of/slashes/afterwards`, and then iterate through the received params as an array or something?

Answer (score 1):

Use `*`. Eg: `<Route path='/thing/*' />`

The URL Params will be available at the `params` prop, e.g. `this.props.params`. The `*` part will be assigned to `splat`, e.g. `this.props.params.splat`.

From the documentation:

> - `()` – Wraps a portion of the URL that is optional
> - `*` – Matches all characters (non-greedy) up to the next character in the pattern, or to the end of the URL if there is none, and creates a
>     splat param
> - `**` - Matches all characters (greedy) until the next /, ?, or # and creates a splat param

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax